# Storing not just 1 file in laravel

Tags: laravel, file

when I tried storing this it worked:

file #1 : `<input type="file" name="file1" multiple id="file1">`

But when I put about 3 of them it didn't.

Is it possible to have not only 1 input type of file?

e.g.

file #1 : `<input type="file" name="file1" multiple id="file1">`

file #2 : `<input type="file" name="file2" multiple id="file2">`

file #3 : `<input type="file" name="file3" multiple id="file3">`

Comment: show the code that are used to store file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have several file input but remember in controller **you have to define upload method for each of them separately**.

Best practice is to use multiple with 1 input only, change the name of input to `name="file1[]"` so you get array and make only 1 method in backend.

**PS**: But it is depend on your needs to use multiple or not, both ways works.

Comment: oh yeah, forgot to put the array. Thanks!